# An error occured during creation of android sub-project.?

Tags: android, cordova, command-line

i am developing a phonegap app using command line.i installed node js.i am using eclipse.When i am trying to use "phonegap --verbose build android" i am getting below error..i added paths in system variable.pls help

```
 E:\Eclipse new version\workspace2\hello> phonegap --verbose build android
 [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
 [phonegap] using the local environment
 [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
 [phonegap] Installing cordova library for android...
 [phonegap] missing library cordova/android/3.3.0
 [phonegap] downloading https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova- 
 android.git;a=snapshot;h=3.3.0;sf=tgz...
 [phonegap] Downloading cordova library for android...
 [phonegap] Download complete
 [phonegap] Installing cordova library for android...
[phonegap] Creating android project...
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.


E:\Eclipse new version\workspace2\hello>
```

System Variable Path

```
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools;
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13;
E:\Node;
C:\Users\ONE\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Users\ONE\.cordova
```

Comment: Have u installed ant ?

Comment: did you try to first run phonegap platform add android?

Comment: i tried to add android using cordova platform add android command.but then also i am getting some errors

Comment: is there a platforms/android folder in your project? if it's a new project and you have a platdorms/android, you can try to remove it and rebuild (it may have been partially created when you first tried with sdk 17).

Answer (score 1):

Today I took my project from one of my pc running phonegap 3.3 to an other one that was still in 3.1. So I upgraded phonegap and then got the same error as you when I tried to build my project for android.

Then I launched `phonegap platform update android` and had an error with a message saying

> Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you
>   have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command
>   -line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.

The other PC was in sdk 19 and this one in sdk 17, so I upgraded to sdk 19 and then relaunched `phonegap platform update android` and the problem was gone.

I guess that maybe phonegap 3.3 needs sdk 19?

Comment: i am using android sdk 19.and set path variables..but still am getting same error.

Comment: Try to run the command `%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` to see what it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you didn't download the 3.3.0 version from your sdk tools:
[image]

or you can update build target in AndroidMainfest.xml file